# How to change soldier into healer and scientist?

Tags: magic

Icefingers is *currently* (in age of wedding of Fairyeyes) very old man (greatly more than 250 years). He is director and chief healer in *house of public health* (hospital) and scientist (if this word may be used in magic world).

But originally, like most young men of his nation, he was enlisted to local army. And he made career in army. He achieved rank of royal executioner.

---

**What may bring soldier to leave army and become healer and scientist?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the actions of a specific character and not about the world he appears in.

Answer (score 3):

**Any number of reasons.**

He might have witnessed a particularly heinous battle, and become disillusioned with the army.

Rather than a specific battle, years of killing might have taken their toll.

He might have started patching up his allies, and decided he likes healing better.

He could have learned that the government was corrupt.

He was ordered to kill innocents.

He killed a group only to learn later they were innocents.

He could have converted to a new religion.

He could belong to a unique religion that allows/requires men to be soldiers when they are young, but stop at a certain age.

Maybe a law of your magic requires equivalent exchange; after a certain number of deaths, he must save a certain number, or risk something (loss of powers?  dying himself?).

There are any number of potential psychological, societal, or religious reasons why he might have changed his profession from soldier to healer.  Without knowing more about the character and setting, it is hard to give a concrete recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen for reasons of pure human psychology, no magic required.  Any soldier who experiences combat, and particularly close-quarters combat, let alone being an executioner, is likely to suffer from post-traumatic-stress-disorder (PTSD).  Humans are conditioned from birth to value the lives of other people in their society, and are predisposed by genetics to require the company of other humans, so the taking of human lives - even those of an enemy - is a traumatic experience.  Even more traumatic is to witness the injury and death of comrades in arms or to be injured in battle.

While some more militaristic societies may have means in place to minimise the incidences of PTSD - often taking the form of post-combat group discussions that have the effect of group therapy - it is inevitable that despite possessing any particularly exceptional combat skills, there may be individuals who are more affected by their military experiences.

Additionally, being an executioner is also traumatic.  While in some societies, those executed may have been found guilty by due process and the executioners insulated as far as possible from the act of taking the condemned's life, in other societies, particularly absolute monarchies or other autocracies, the monarch or autocrat may be more arbitrary as to the imposition of sentences of death, potentially ordering the execution of innocents for no reason other than opposing political views or even a whim or fit of pique.  An executioner in this environment - who may also be required to take a more personal hand in performing the execution, such as decapitating or strangling the condemned in person - is more likely to suffer from PTSD, especially if required to conceal any disagreement with the sentence in order to maintain personal safety.

It has been shown [that more intelligent individuals suffer less from Ptsd](http://www.apa.org/monitor/apr02/higheriq.aspx), however, this may be due to the greater possibilities for an intelligent individual to find ways to minimise the effects.  It is certainly possible that the OP's battle-hardened executioner may have been an intelligent individual who became affected by PTSD, and to compensate, took the personal choice to change their life from one of bringing death to one dedicated to saving lives, not only using accepted and known medical practises, but also by discovering new and better ways to save lives.

Pursuing such a career could have the effect of allowing this individual to feel that he is atoning for the many deaths he has caused and to feel that his fellow countrymen need not die pointlessly if he can save them.